# unable to run jupyter notebook in vscode even when ipykernel is installed and still it shows it is not

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, plugins, pip, jupyter-notebook

I have used vscode for jupyter notebook for a long time, but suddenly when one day I open any notebook it gives an error

> ***Python 3.9.2 64-bit requires ipykernel to be installed.***".

I have it installed as I have been using notebook frequently and when I install it using pip, it says that it is already installed. I tried by reinstalling all the plugins of vscode, downgrading the jupyter plugin, forxe reinstalling the the ipykernel plugin except reinstalling python as `.py` file are working fine. I tried all the methods and restarted my computer too but it still didn't work.

I have attached an image showing that I tried to install it and then on running it didn't run.

[image: image showing that I tried to install it and then on running it didn't run .]

Comment: If you click on the Python 3.9.2 text (bottom left) and it shows two python options, try the other one. If there is not two then I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the python environment currently used by Jupyter is different from the python environment currently used by the VS Code terminal.

1. Please use the command "`python --version`" or "`pip --version`" to check the python currently used by the VS Code terminal:

   [image]
2. Then install "ipykernel". (`pip install ipykernel`)
3. In the upper right corner of Jupyter, select the python environment used by the terminal.

In addition, it is recommended that you make sure that the lower left corner of VS Code, the VS Code terminal, and Jupyter use the same python environment.

[image]

More references: [Jupyter in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support) and [Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by running VS Code as Administrator and reinstalling ipykernel through VS Code again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the mentioned solutions but it did not work for me.
Finally I solved by activating conda env in VS code terminal and then executed this command. VS code was able to detect the ipykernel now.

```
conda install -p <your_env> ipykernel --update-deps --force-reinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem just now, even though I was running Python 3.9.
vscode kept telling me to install ipykernel, even though it was already installed in that environment.

The problem was that the default ipykernel installation always installed ipykernel version 5.5.5.
When I forced it to install ipykernel 6.15,  jupyter worked properly in vscode.
I used:
conda install -c conda-forge ipykernel==6.15

pip install and the default conda channel could not install version 6.15

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34504107)

Answer (score -1):

Running

```
sudo apt-get install python3-ipykernel
```

worked for me.

Comment: This answer has already been provided, if you wish to add to that answer saying it worked for you please use the "comment" feature on that answer.

Comment: @Mixone I don't see it in the other answers...